# Android - Visually impactful representation of small but important data

Tags: mobile, android, visual-design, carousel

I am building an app where lets say I have four to five very important terms, clicking which take me to separate activities. I want these terms to be visually impactful in what they convey and how they are portrayed . I have one screen completely allocated to displaying these, so I have a lot of real estate to work with. For instance, lets say i am building a sports app and my five things are

```
1.) Cricket
2.)Football
3.) Baseball
4.) NBA
5.) NFL
```

Lets say I have one pretty good image for each of them, to represent them and some little data to show on screen about them. 
I have thought of using a carousel to represent them, but carousel seem to not be preferred by many, because it is almost like it has one time appeal, and then it gets annoying after a bit. Is this true? I dont want a simple list view. Are there any alternative representations in android that anyone else can suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its going to be hard to represent a suitable solution unless we get an idea about the type of content you are going to show with the image since the size of the content could decide how much screen space could be shown.

I am not a fan of using a carousal since its a one time view for a single image at one point and does not provide equal value to all images unless the user navigates to that image. I do prefer having a list view like this example here since its easy to navigate and can display quite a bit of information at one shot :

[image]

But I remember you mentioning you were not looking for a simple list view.

Another option would be to use large tile like options which would allow you to show images and you can overlay text like headlines on them

[image]

Or you could go the pinterest route :

[image]

The eventual design will depend on you and I would recommend going through some good Mobile UI patterns to see if there are any specific examples you like:

[Pttrns](http://pttrns.com/)

[Mobile UI Patterns](http://mobile-patterns.com/)

[Inspired UI](http://inspired-ui.com/)

[Lovely UI](http://www.lovelyui.com/)

**Note**: I know a lot of the above examples and sites are more Iphone specific but you can adapt design ideas from them as needed